# Elastic Search 5+ query multiple exact values

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i am using python 3.5 and elasicsearch 5.6.3:

```
deplist = ['A', 'B']
body = {"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "terms": {
                        "Department": deplist}}}}}
res = es.search(index=self.index, doc_type='data', body=body)
```

but i dont have results, If i do i have results:

```
body = {"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "match": {
                        "Department": 'A'}}}}}
res = es.search(index=self.index, doc_type='data', body=body)
```

Comment: I guess you should use `json.load` while ingesting the data. https://github.com/hkulekci/es-presentation-examples/blob/master/twitter/stream.py#L17-L21

Answer (score 0):

Convert the query into JSON encoding before searching. Use `json.dumps(body)`.